# Dropna does not drop the row with NON value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to clean my dataset and remove all the rows with missing values, here I am using Dropno() but it actually doesn't remove anything from dataframe.

here is my code:

```
url_list = ['https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
            'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/cardano/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
           'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/chainlink/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel']


dfList = []

for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    src = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
    
    data = []
    coin = url.split("/")[5].upper()
    for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
        
        data.append(
            dict(zip([f'{x.text}_{coin}' for x in soup.select('thead th')], [x.text.strip() for x in row.select('th,td') ]))
        )
        
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df['Date_'+str(coin)] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_'+str(coin)])
        
        df = df.dropna(how='any')           
        df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)  
     
    

          

    dfList.append(df)
    

dfList[0]
```

and here is the output of df.info()

> [image: Blockquote]

[image]

Comment: Are there `NaN` values in your data frame?

Comment: I added an image of dataframe, i basically want to drop the first row which includes N/A

Comment: I'm guessing here that `N/A` is actual string data containing the characters `"N/A"` and, as such, is not `NaN`. Instead you need to filter out rows that contain that string. Instead something like: `df = df[df['Close_CHAINLINK'] != 'N/A']`

Comment: getting error : KeyError: 'Close_ETHEREUM'

Comment: I have added a full code for better undrestanding

Answer (score 2):

From the listing above it looks like all of your values are non-null. N/A is a string representation and not considered a missing value.

Try

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('N/A', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Here is pandas documentation on missing data:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

Comment: I have added an image of dataframe

Comment: still not working

Comment: I've updated my answer to include inplace=True, did that still not fix it? Can you print the index containing N/A and find out what type it is? I was assuming it is a string: try type(df.iloc[0, 4]) and print(df.iloc[0, 4])